# Prove that measure of $A$ is $1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A\subset (0,1)$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and $\lambda>0$. Suppose that if $0\le a<b\le 1$ then $\mu(A\cap (a,b))\ge \lambda(b-a)$. Prove that $\mu(A)=1$.

It is clear that $\lambda \le 1$ and to show $\mu(A)=1$ is equivalent to show that $\mu(A^c)=0$.

Comment: $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Since Lebesgue measure is regular, if $\mu(A^C\cap(0,1))>0$, there is an open set $O\subset(0,1)$ with $\mu(A\cap O)<\lambda$. Write $O$ as a countable union of disjoint open intervals $O_i$. We must have $\mu(A\cap O_i)<\lambda\mu(O_i)$ for some $i$.

Comment: @user133281 yes $\mu$ dentotes Lebesgue Measure

Comment: If you know about the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, you can also use this.

Comment: @PhoemueX I've started learning Measure theory , so not familiar with the theorems.

Comment: @DavidMitra Sir can you provide me some basic proof, I don't have any idea about regularity and other things.

Comment: The property used is: If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an open set $O$ containing $A$ such that $\mu(O\setminus A)<\epsilon$. You should find a proof of this in any measure theory text.  In my previous comment, you find $O$ containing $A^C$ with $\mu(O\setminus A^C)<\lambda$ (and then $\mu(O\cap A)<\lambda$).

Answer (score 1):

by the constraction of lebesgue measure,

$\mu (A)=inf\{ \sum \mu(E_n): A \subset \cup E_n\ , E_n$ are disjoint intervals $\}$

hence for any $\epsilon >0$ there are disjoint intervals $E_1 ... E_N$ such that $\mu (A \Delta \cup^N_{n=1}E_n)< \epsilon$.

on the other hand, clearly $(\cup^N_{n=1}E_n)^c=\cup^M_{m=1}F_m$, where $\{F_m\}^M_{m=1}$ are also disjoint intervals (closed/semi-closed/open). Thus, we get:

$\epsilon>\mu (A \cap (\cup^M_{m=1}F_m)) \geq \lambda (1-\mu(\cup^N_{n=1}E_n)) >\lambda(1-\mu(A)+\epsilon)$, so

$\epsilon /\lambda -\epsilon > 1-\mu(A)$ , for any $\epsilon >0$  ,which is $\mu(A)=1$